# PassportJS and local strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I get an issue using PassportJS and my local strategy. I'm using ExpressJS 4.

**My app.js (reduced, without express init) :**

```
var express                        = require('express'),
    ejs                            = require('ejs'),
    path                           = require('path'),
    expressLayouts                 = require('express-ejs-layouts'),
    session                        = require('express-session'),
    compression                    = require('compression'),

    _                              = require('lodash'),
    fs                             = require('fs-extra'),
    colors                         = require('colors'),
    passport                       = require('passport'),
    flash                          = require('connect-flash'),

    localStrategyMiddleware        = require('./middlewares/localStrategy'),
    logMiddleware                  = require('./middlewares/log'),
    localsMiddleware               = require('./middlewares/locals'),
    securityMiddleware             = require('./middlewares/security');

this.app.use(session({
  secret : 'd4qs45sdq6',
  // name : 'sessionId',
  // proxy: true,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

this.app.use(flash());
this.app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  response.locals.flash = {
    info: request.flash('info'),
    success: request.flash('success'),
    warning: request.flash('warning'),
    danger: request.flash('danger')
  };
  next();
});

this.app.use(passport.initialize());
this.app.use(passport.session());

this.app.post('/test', passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/user/success',
      failureRedirect: '/user/failure',
      failureFlash: true,
      successFlash: true
    }), function(request, response) {
  console.log('test');
});
```

**My strategy (`./middlewares/localStrategy`) :**

```
var passport        = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    sequelize       = require('../databases/Database').connexion,
    UserModel       = require('../app/models/UserModel')(sequelize);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {

    console.log('test');

    UserModel.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }

      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log(id);
  UserModel.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

module.exports = passport;
```

Issue : I get no logs and I'm every time redirected to `user/failure`.

**Edit 1 :**

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%=csrfToken%>">
  <input type="text" name="user[username]" placeholder="username">
  <input type="text" name="user[password]" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Just saying, I have found that once I understood how authentication works in general, that it was easier for me to handroll a solution than to use passport. But I'm sure there could be things I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting no logs then that tells you that your app.js file doesn't have access to the code in  `./middlewares/localStrategy`

Try changing

`localStrategyMiddleware = require('./middlewares/localStrategy')`

to simply

```
require('./middlewares/localStrategy')
```

Also you need to change your name attributes on your form to match with those that passport uses, I think the default are username and password, so unless you want to specify alternatives in your localStrategy you should use the following.

```
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
```

Comment: It doesn"t work too. I'm not able to get the `console.log('test');`... But I think the function `function(username, password, done)` is not still executed...

Comment: In your POST request form, what names have you used? Do they match with username and password?

Comment: The action in the form view is correct and if I remove the authentication the route works.

Comment: My question may not have been clear, have you set the attribute names for your form inputs to username and password? Might be easiest if you add your form code to your question.